# Location Updates in Background Android 10

Tags: android, location, android-10.0

i have worked with https://github.com/android/location-samples  (pending intent one)and everythink works great for old device (level 24) but the background service doesn't work on android 10. 
Do you have any ideas why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) on the all android version that have API level 26 or greater.

In order to provide user more better battery life and performance. Google started restrictions. now if application is not foreground then background service will not work. you have to make service as a foreground service that will always notify user that your app is running in background.